# What to do when manual focus doesn't work on a Nikon DX lens after DIY repair?

Tags: troubleshooting, manual-focus, repair

I have a Nikon 55-200mm DX auto focus lens. I recently repaired the bayonet mount myself - all went well. But when I went to use the manual focus option on the lens, the focus ring remained locked, as it is on autofocus. Any suggestions as to what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You've switched the lens switch from A to M then?

Comment: "I recently repaired the bayonet mount myself - all went well." Not to sound mean, but I don't think that sounds like the case. Modern lenses are much more electronic, I think you should probably look to have it serviced by Nikon.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the release from the AF motor is not functioning.  I would recommend having it serviced by Nikon.

Comment: I have switched the A to M mode...and I am not sure if I did something to damage the man focus mode  when I repaired the bayonet mount, or if this is a different problem, as I didn't try to manually focus until 2 months later....